# VS2008 Crystal Reports Database Connection from Web.config

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, web-config, database-connection

I have an ASP.NET application I'm developing. In it is a CR report. When I first wrote the report, I had it hard coded to point to my development server (using MSSQL with Windows integrated login). So, when I moved my app to the production server, it of course failed.
I have been searching for an answer on how to connect it to DB listed in the Web.config, but haven't had any luck.

I saw one suggestion that I create a dataset in my project and tie in to that, but now it seems I can't use a parameter to filter the records.
I did see one other suggestion on how you can change the DB source on the fly, but that was designed for those who want to change the DB in mid session, rather than dependent on the machine, and seemed overkill.

Does anyone have a nice simple solution? I have been working on this problem for way too long and feel that I'm about to shoot my computer (that will teach it a lesson). :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class ReportDocumentExtensions
{
    public static void SetConnectionInfo(this ReportDocument report, ReportContextArgs context)
    {
        SetConnectionInfo(report, context.UserId, context.Password, context.ServerName, context.DatabaseName);
    }

    public static void SetConnectionInfo(this ReportDocument report, string userId, string password, string serverName, string databaseName)
    {
        foreach (Table oTable in report.Database.Tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo oInfo = oTable.LogOnInfo;

            ConnectionInfo oConnection = oTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

            oConnection.UserID = userId;
            oConnection.Password = password;
            oConnection.ServerName = serverName;
            oConnection.DatabaseName = databaseName;

            oTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(oInfo);
        }
    }
}

public class ReportContextArgs
{

    private string _userId;
    private string _password;
    private string _serverName;
    private string _databaseName;

    public string ServerName
    {
        get { return _serverName; }
        set { _serverName = value; }
    }

    public string UserId
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set { _userId = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { _password = value; }
    }

    public string DatabaseName
    {
        get { return _databaseName; }
        set { _databaseName = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, but that's just changing it at run time. And if I have a lot of reports, then I would have to change each one. I thought that having a connection set up in the web.config meant that you only had to change the connection in one place for the entire application.

Comment: One problem with Crystal Reports is that the connection information is hard-coded into the binary report for certain types of data-sources. This is a maintainence issue that plagues everyone. (There are a few non-connection scenarios that CR supports, like using a data-set as you mentioned.) In your case, with the information provided, you have to do make this change at run-time. I, and everyone else, feels your pain.

Comment: If you provide one centralized method/page to "display the report", which I suggested you use, then changing the data-source is a non-issue. For instance, in a project I inherited, there are over 50 reports that used direct access connection to the physical tables on the server and OLE DB connections. It took about a day to get all the reports directed to two "viewers" where I made the run-time change. (I use two viewers, because it was impossible to standardize on one viewer.) I used args and an extension method. Therefore, that actual connection change is one line of code.

Comment: Notice I use `ReportContextArgs`. On startup, parse your connection string from the web.config, initialize a `ReportContextArgs`, and store for use in the `ReportDocument.SetConnectionInfo` call.

Comment: OK, I thought it must be something I missed, but I guess what I want just isn't possible. And as much as I'd like to blame MS on this, it really sounds more of an SAP issue. 
Thanks for the advise. I'm going to implement it tomorrow.